# Multi-threading for Scala stream production and processing

Tags: multithreading, scala, stream, producer-consumer

Suppose that I have a fairly standard producer/consumer problem to code up in Scala, with this sort of structure:

1. Construct either a `Stream` or an `Iterator` that lazily generates elements.
2. Use `map` or `foreach` on the `Stream` or `Iterator` to process these elements and do something with them.

This seems to work well, but it looks like it's single-threaded: when we want to process a new element, we ask for it to be generated, and after it's been generated, then we get to work on it. What I'd really like is a mechanism for the generation to continue while the previous element is being processed. Is there a way of getting Scala to do this?

I'm aware that I could use a `BlockingQueue`, but that seems terribly imperative to me. I'm hoping there's a way to have a `Stream` keep on generating elements on another thread.

Once we're generating them in advance, it's not lazy evaluation any more, of course. But nor do I want eager evaluation that generates the whole stream in advance. I want the analogue of a `BlockingQueue`, but in a functional paradigm.

Comment: You should look into reactive streams. See http://reactive-streams.org . An implementation using scala and akka has just reached 1.0 milestone 1 state. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/PPleJEfI5sM/EpSGOK2Pah4J. Each stream processing stage lives on its own actor, so you should be able to get very good concurrency. In the long term, this should even allow you to distribute a stream processing pipeline over multiple machines.

Comment: There are various iteratee-based approaches that allow both sides to be appropriately async. I think scalaz-stream is the big current effort in this direction. "Continuous" processes allow something fully reactive (though I haven't worked with them directly); what I do is to "fake it" by combining fully pure `Task`s with judicious use of `unsafeStart`.

Comment: I believe `scalaz-stream` is closest to what you are looking for. Akka streams also provides a functional wrapper over Akka actors for stream processing. The biggest difference between these two being that Akka streams support back pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map items from your stream to a future of processing like this:

```
def process(x: Int): Int = // do something time consuming
val asyncProducer = Stream.from(0).map(x => future { process(x)})
```

Now this produces nothing, since Stream won't generate items until you try to materialize them, pretty much like you suggest your stream works. So if you want to fire off the processing of the next 10 items, you can simply materialize them like this:

```
val futureResults = asyncProducer.take(10).toList
```

This will start 10 parallel processes (depending on the ExecutionContext you have in scope) and produce a `List[Future[Int]]`. To get be able to receive all those work items, you can then sequence to list of future's into a future of a list:

```
val futureResult = Future.sequence(futureResults)
```

Now this future you can map to get a list of results and hand them off to some recipient and start the next chunk of processing.